# SystemC Transfer Level Modeling Extract Two Integers from tlm_generic_payload

Tags: c++, systemc

I am working with the SystemC TLM library. I would like to send a payload with two integers to a module that will perform an operation on those two integers. My question is simply how to setup and decode the payload.

Doulos provided documentation on both setting up and decoding here https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/systemc/tlm2/tutorial__1/

Setup

```
tlm::tlm_command cmd = static_cast(rand() % 2);
if (cmd == tlm::TLM_WRITE_COMMAND) data = 0xFF000000 | i;

trans->set_command( cmd );
trans->set_address( i );
trans->set_data_ptr( reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&data) );
trans->set_data_length( 4 );
trans->set_streaming_width( 4 );
trans->set_byte_enable_ptr( 0 );
trans->set_dmi_allowed( false );
trans->set_response_status( tlm::TLM_INCOMPLETE_RESPONSE );

socket->b_transport( *trans, delay );
```

Decode

```
virtual void b_transport( tlm::tlm_generic_payload& trans, sc_time& delay )
{
  tlm::tlm_command cmd = trans.get_command();
  sc_dt::uint64    adr = trans.get_address() / 4;
  unsigned char*   ptr = trans.get_data_ptr();
  unsigned int     len = trans.get_data_length();
  unsigned char*   byt = trans.get_byte_enable_ptr();
  unsigned int     wid = trans.get_streaming_width();
```

So it looks to me like you would send a pointer to a memory location where there are two integers written.

|----------------------------------int1-------------------------|------------------------------------int2------------------------

|ptr+0x0|ptr+0x(wid)|ptr+0x(2*wid)|ptr+0x(3*wid) | ptr+0x(4*wid)|ptr+0x(5*wid)|ptr+0x(6*wid)|ptr+0x

----------|

(7*wid)|

Is my interpretation of this documentation correct?

How could you get those first 4 memory locations [3:0] and combine them into an int32 and how could you get the second 4 [7:4] and turn them into the second integer?

Comment: In general you should use high-level libraries like SCML that provide more user-friendly APIs on top of raw TLM-2.0. Generic payload is designed for tool interoperability, end-users should better use high-level APIs provided by EDA vendor.

Comment: is scml open source? where are the include files in v2.3.2

Comment: It can be downloaded from https://www.synopsys.com/cgi-bin/slcw/kits/reg.cgi .  There are other similar libraries, for example greenlib: https://github.com/GreenSocs/greenlib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So it looks to me like you would send a pointer to a memory location
>   where there are two integers written.
>   Is my interpretation of this documentation correct?

Yes

To get them back you just need to copy them:

```
int32_t val0, val1;
memcpy(&val0, ptr, sizeof(int32_t));
memcpy(&val1, ptr + sizeof(int32_t), sizeof(int32_t));
```

or something like

```
int32_t val[2];
memcpy(val, ptr, sizeof val);
```

But make sure initiator keeps memory under the pointer valid long enough e.g. it might be better to avoid using keep data on the stack. And don't forget to check if payloads data length attribute has valid value - you want to detect those issues as soon as possible.